# how to check with css if an image was loaded or if the alternative is displaying?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply the following style only if the image is not loaded and the default is being displayed.

```
#chat-log section .msg img.avatar{
   background: purple;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 10px;
}
```

But if I apply it when the image is found and loaded it will distort the image.
Here is the image

```
<img src="http://imageipsum.com/1200x675" alt="D" class="avatar">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it in a "div" like the following code. This will put the purple in the background and if the picture does not load it will display. If the picture loads then it will cover up this "div":

CSS example (use your own classes and what not):

```
    .avatar {
        background: purple;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        width: 1200px;
        height: 675px;
    }
    .alt {
        padding-top: 26%;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

HTML example:

```
<div class="avatar">
    <img src="http://imageipsum.com/1200x675">
    <div class="alt">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: my problem actually is with the padding top that affects the img display

Comment: if i add the padding top to the div.avatar it will shift the img down.

Comment: Could adding "margin-top: 10px;" to the div help you instead of "padding top"?

Comment: the margin wont help. what am trying to do is to centralize the alt D when it is displayed.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are trying to "align" the "D" to be centered both vertically and horizontally in the purple background when the image is not displayed?

Comment: you got it. that's what I want to do

Comment: Edited my answer; down and dirty way of accomplishing what you are trying to do.